# Docker Node image generates files with wrong user permissions

Tags: docker, npm

## Problem

I'm using docker to generate my npm files. The problem is I get permissions issues when I do this. I have been using second alpine image to fix the permission issues. I want to speed up the process by generating the files with the correct permissions.

### Attempt 1

Using the node user seemed to work at first as it persisted the user permissions on my device. When I tried it on a different device I got this error which I could not solve. The /local directory is where I'm mounting my npm directory. I also tried adding the group to the node user and got the same error.

#### Code

```bash
docker run -u "node" --rm -v $PWD:/local node:19.3.0 bash -c "cd local/mobile && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npx ionic build && npx ionic cap copy"
```

#### Output

> npm ERR! path /local/mobile/node_modules

> npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR!

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/local/mobile/node_modules'

> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

> '/local/mobile/node_modules']

> { npm ERR!   errno: -13,

> npm ERR!
> code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',

> npm ERR!   path:
> '/local/mobile/node_modules' npm ERR! }

### Attempt 2

I also tried using my local id and group id to run the dockerfile. I got a different error when using this technique.

#### Code

```bash
docker run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" --rm -v $PWD:/local node:19.3.0 bash -c "cd local/mobile && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npx ionic build && npx ionic cap copy"
```

#### Output

> npm ERR! code EACCES

> npm ERR! syscall mkdir

> npm ERR! path /.npm npm

> ERR! errno -13

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the user node. By default, the user "node" haven not have written permission the host machine

You try the following method

`docker run --rm -v $PWD:/local node:19.3.0 bash -c "cd local/mobile && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npx ionic build && npx ionic cap copy"`

Comment: The method you're describing creates the files as the root user. And specifying the node user gives an error. See my first attempt